# Initialize NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I am developing an **iOS** application in which I want to use an `NSMutableDictionary`. Basically what I am doing is converting java code to objectiveC.

So in java I have something like this:

```
Map<String, ClassA> dict1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer,Character> dict2 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, Map<String,String>> dict3 = new HashMap<>();
```

Can someone please guide me as what would be the Obj-C equivalent code for the above three lines using `NSMutableDictionary` and also how can I set and get the pairs in/from the dictionaries.

Comment: Did you have a look at the NS(Mutable)Dictionary documentation or the ["Collections Programming Topics"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html) guide with all its example code?

Comment: Do a web search on "How to use NSMutableDictionary". If you write code and are stuck on a issue we'd be happy to help, but it doesn't appear you've taken the first steps yet.

Comment: @MartinR No, didn't know about this!!
Thanks, will go through it now.

Comment: @DBD Please don't get me wrong, I really did go through anything and everything i could find on this but was yet confused on `Map<"anything which comes here">` part

Comment: That's probably because generics don't exist in Objective-C. The tutorials are all good and will work, you just can't enforce only a specific data type going into the dictionary. I miss my generics in Obj-C too, but it's not so bad. Like going commando!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Objective-C collection classes are not strongly typed so all three dictionaries would be created using:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictX = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

In order to populate the dictionary use [`[NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/setObject:forKey:):

```
[dict1 setObject:classAInstance
          forKey:@"key1"];
[dict2 setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", character]
          forKey:@(1)];
[dict3 setObject:@{ @"innerKey" : @"innerValue" }
          forKey:@(2)];
```

etc.

Comment: How would I populate dict3?
Will it be like
`[dict3 setObject:NSMutableDictionary *abc forKey:??]` as key here is an Integer

Comment: Great!! Specific to my need.

Answer (score 11):

Since Objective C does not have generic types all you have to type is this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dict3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

There's a couple ways to get and set values. The shorthand form is much like accessing arrays.
To set a value with shorthand:

```
dict1[@"key"] = @"value";
```

To get a value with shorthand:

```
NSString *value = dict1[@"key"];
```

More verbose syntax is like so:

```
[dict1 setObject:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
NSString *value = [dict1 valueForKey:@"key"];
```

Comment: What about dict3, as it has a dictionary inside??

Comment: @Sibir It doesn't matter what kind of object is inside.